# Jquery Ajax passing array inside data obect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass an object into the data property of this jquery ajax request. All work's fine, but the `fields` property, which is an array, does not get recognized (returns all fields, when these are the two I am requesting).

I've tried `JSON.stringify`, but this returns an error for 'bad request'. How do I pass this object with an array inside correctly?

```
function energyQuery(token){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Token token=' + token},
        data: {
                'start': '2019-01-05',
                'end': '2019-01-10',
                'limit': 0,
                'measurement': 'analysis',
                'fields': ['energy_out', 'energy_in']  // if I pass 'energy_out' it works
            },
        success: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            response = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(errMsg) {
            console.log('Query:' + JSON.stringify(errMsg));
        }
    });
}
```

error message:

```
Please note that fields MUST either be a single valid field string or a list of valid field strings.
```

Comment: try by changing `GET` to `POST`

Answer (score 0):

Send it as post and point to correct datatype

```
var array = ['energy_out', 'energy_in'];
var dataObj = {
            'start': '2019-01-05',
            'end': '2019-01-10',
            'limit': 0,
            'measurement': 'analysis',
            'fields': array 
        };
        var data = JSON.stringify(dataObj);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
```

Also on back-end side create correct model to recieve data.

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to be a 'GET', and I've tried this method previously - it ignores the 'field' property completely.

Comment: So do you trying to filter data by those params and get only fields that is energy_out and energy_in ?

Comment: What are you using as backend?

Comment: Yes. If I try `energy_out`, it returns just the energy_out data. but when I try submit an array, like above, it returns all of the fields. (see error message included).

Comment: I normally use Python for these requests. In that case, passing a python list works, as above.

Comment: And that error coming from back-end or front-end? I think it does relate on how your back-end handling that data, because "data" param in ajax call is whatever data you put there. So if it failing to send that post request it is one thing, but if it send it successfully and back-end send that response, you need to check what data back-end expecting. I usually using OData for that kind of requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing also the server side, please consider to change the array of strings to a "particular string".

What I mean?

CASE 1 : pass array as string

```
'fields': '[\'energy_out\', \'energy_in\'])'
```

Then in the server side read the string and convert it to an array.
This is the solution that I use in Java: I read a String then I convert it to an array of integer,strings,... and so on.

CASE 2: use a particular separator, pass the field as a string;

```
'fields': 'value1,value2,value3'
```

Supposing you use `,` as separator, then you must split string by `,`.

It's better to ask (via web service) arrays as a single string so each client can implement in a simple way of to pass data in the get method.

Answer (score -1):

`'fields': ['energy_out', 'energy_in']`

It's not a standard json format. just change the type of parameter 0 `'fields': 'energy_out,energy_in'` and when receive use split`,`

Comment: change the type of param. 0

'fields': 'energy_out,energy_in'' and when receive use split","